# "Мыльница". Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: значение-слов, кавычки

*Обязательны* ли кавычки к слову "мыльница" — по отношению к простому фотоаппарату.
(Текст литературный, поэтому мелочь важна.)

Answer (score 2):

Что такое "литературный текст"...
Если из текста ясно, что речь идет о фотоаппарате, то я бы сказал, что кавычки можно не ставить. Все знают, что мыльницами называют простенькие фотоаппараты. А если, например, так: *"Он пошел <...>, вооружившись только "мыльницей"* — то надо.

В любом случае кавычки ошибкой не будут.

Comment: Под "литературным тексом" я имел ввиду, что он планируется к опубликованию с правами (+ISBN), а не, к примеру, на сайте "Проза ру", где не возбраняется писать (специально) с орфографическими ошибками. Вопрос от обратного: будел ли ошибкой отсутствие кавычек? Хотя, следующие два участника мне на него уже ответили.

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки не нужны, если ясно, что речь идет о фотоаппарате. Слово "мыльница" в значении фотоаппарата фиксируется словарями.

См.: [Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/bts/)

Answer (score 1):

Если в тексте говорится, что под мыльницей подразумевается именно фотоаппарат, то можно и не ставить. А если нет, то нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Я за кавычки, и плевать на Кузнецова: он в гордом одиночестве к тому же делает помету "разг.". Если в Вашем +ISBN "мыльница" упомянута в прямой речи персонажа, более склонного к разговорно-просторечной лексике + из контекста ясно, об чём речь, - не кавычьте. Если текст "от автора" - будьте так любезны...

У меня нет "мыльницы", молодёжный сленг мне негде подслушивать: я как читатель не пойму, как редактор - сочту браком.

Comment: Галина, мыльница в значении фотоаппарат фиксируется и у Ефремовой, Ожегова.   Грамота то же говорит, что кавычки не нужны. Образность уже давно стерлось.

Comment: В моем тексте мыльница упомянута в словах автора, более того, она в заголовке. Если я поставлю кавычки, потеряется шарм.( Как будто рассказал анекдот, затем пояснил, в каком месте нужно было смеяться.) Молодежный сленг здесь не очень имеет месть быть. Мыльницами называли дешевые пленочные фотоаппараты. Врядли современная молодежь знает что такое фотопленка.

Comment: Серж, спасибо, приму к сведению. Виктор, вся ситуация у Вас в руках вкупе со словарями, - чем тогда вызван вопрос? Я человек пожилой, и для меня мыльница - емкость для мыла, не более. На плёночные аппараты я снимала несколько десятилетий и ни от кого не слышала, что снимаю мыльницей.

Comment: @Галина, если честно, и  я до этого вопроса не знал об этом значении.